# Aggregating Variables in dependency of date

Tags: r

I have a big dataset with a lot of date-points and datapoints. See here for a minimal example.

```
Date     x     y     id     update-size
01.01    1     1      1
01.02    2     3      1     2345
01.03    4     2      1
01.01    5     7      2     3654
01.02    2     6      2
01.03    3     2      2     4789
```

I want to aggregate the data (x, y) between each software update. To put it in words: If there is an update take all the data between this update and the last update (or the first data point) and aggregate them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the expected output for the example showed.   It is not clear about what how you want to aggregate

Answer (score 0):

Functions like `aggregate` and `tapply` as well as tools in the `plyr`, `dplyr` and related packages will do the aggregating for you.  But these all expect a single variable that defines the groups to aggregate.

For your simple example you could create the grouping variable using code like:

```
group <- cumsum(!is.na(mydata[['update-size']])
```

Another option, if you have the dates for the updates, is to use the `findInterval` function.

Example:

```
> mydata <- data.frame(Date=c('01.01','01.02','01.03','01.01','01.02','01.03'),
+                    x=c(1,2,4,5,2,5),
+                    y=c(1,3,2,7,6,2),
+                    id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
+                    update.size =c(NA,2345,NA,2345,NA,4789)
+ )
> 
> group <- cumsum(!is.na(mydata$update.size))
> 
> # above aggregates with values after update
> # this line changes to aggregate with before
> group[ !is.na(mydata$update.size) ] <- group[ !is.na(mydata$update.size) ] -1
> 
> 
> aggregate(mydata[,2:4], list(group), FUN=sum)
  Group.1 x y id
1       0 3 4  2
2       1 9 9  3
3       2 7 8  4
>
```